# Counting words in a String that are separated by other string

Tags: c

I have to count the words in a string using other string separator. For example if I have a string `"akjvnrupajcruamvoq"` and separator `"ru"` it must return 2 and if I have `"dadadadada"` and a separator `"da"` it must return 0. I have troubles with counting the words after I found a separator.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int wc(char* pcSource, char* pcSeparator)
{ 
  int iWordsCount=0;
  int iI=0;
  int  iJ=0;
  int iK=0;
  int iCharCount=0;
  int iLenghtOfSeparator=strlen(pcSeparator);
  int iLenghtOfSource=strlen(pcSource);
  
  for (iI; iI < iLenghtOfSource; iI++)
  { 
    iK=iI;
    if ((iK != 0) && (iK != iLenghtOfSource - iLenghtOfSeparator))
    {
      while (iJ < iLenghtOfSeparator)
      {
        if (pcSource[iK] == pcSeparator[iJ])
        {
          iK++;
        } 
        if (pcSource[iK] != pcSeparator[iJ])
        {
          iCharCount++;
          iK++;
        }
        iJ++;
      }
    }

outOfLoop:
    if (iCharCount == iLenghtOfSeparator)
    {
      iWordsCount++;
    }

    iJ=0; 
    iCharCount=0;
  }
  
  return iWordsCount;
}

int main()
{
  int iMaxSize=2048;
  char pcSource[]="cocacola";
  char pcSeparator[]="co";
  int iWordsCount;

  iWordsCount = wc(pcSource,pcSeparator);
  printf("Words count in this string are: %d",iWordsCount);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should it return 2 resp. 0 in your examples?

Comment: I would assume your first example results in 3 words: `"akjvn", "pajc", "amvoq"`

Comment: Yes it is 3 not 2.

Comment: See [here](https://onlinegdb.com/FhZXl_dyI) a version of your code that you may want to compare to yours

Comment: Hint: 1 hamburger pattie separates 2 bun-halves... unless it is "open-face", and/or just a pattie sitting on a plate. How many separators are there?

Comment: @kikon thats version is really helpful but unfortunately it didnt give the results i need. If i input string only with separators it still give me that there is a word.

Comment: @kikon and if my string is adscoco and the separator is co it return 2.

Comment: The result is not always a unique number. For example, if the separator is "dad", the number of words in "dadadad" could be 1 ("dad-a-dad") or 2 ("da-dad-ad").

Comment: @ВалентинД. my bad - it should have been `for (; iI < iLenghtOfSource - iLenghtOfSeparator + 1; iI++)`. I made a  [new version](https://onlinegdb.com/BXji9WkXX) with debug `printf`s so you can work better the differences

Comment: @kikon thank you so much. I have only one question. Why the loop is until iLenghtOfSource - iLenghtOfSeparator + 1. Just cannot understand this algorithm

Comment: @ВалентинД. I would've put it better as `iI <= iLenghtOfSource - iLenghtOfSeparator` (the same thing). So for the `"adscoco"` example the last `iI` should be 5 - comparing with `"co"` chars at 5 and 6 (last two). I think the main difference from your version is that I allow for the separator to be found even at the beginning and at the end but analyse what's the effect of that find. Coming back to the example, if the last two characters were not `"co"` - the result would have been 2 - so you see it's relevant to find the separator even at the end.

Comment: Also - food for though: @nielsen 's comment is very interesting - you should define if separator `"dad"` matches the second `dad` in `"dadad"` or not. I naively set the main pointer `iI` to the end of the match (`iI = iK - 1`) preventing the second find. So my version doesn't find it while your version, that only incremented  `iI` even in the case of a match, was supposed to find the second `dad`.

Comment: @ВалентинД. nielsen's comment (and kikon's one later) is one of the main points to fix in you question. You should have a clear definition of what you should obtain. An option is to define a process/algorithm which leads to the desired result, even if it's not the most efficient implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
Commented lines should explain what is happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int wc(char* pcSource, char* pcSeparator)
{
    int iWordsCount=0;
    int iI=0;
    int iJ=0;
    int iK=0;
    int iStartSubStr = 0;

    while ( pcSource[iI]) // not terminating zero
    {
        iJ = 0;
        if ( pcSource[iI] == pcSeparator[iJ]) // start of separator
        {
            iK = 0;
            while ( pcSeparator[iJ]) // not terminating zero
            {
                if (pcSource[iK + iI] != pcSeparator[iJ]) // not the same
                {
                    break;
                }
                iK++;
                iJ++;
            }
            if ( ! pcSeparator[iJ]) // terminating zero
            {
                if ( iStartSubStr != iI) // skip if substring begins with separator
                {
                    ++iWordsCount;
                }
                iStartSubStr = iI + iK; // set start of next sub string
                iI += iK;
            }
            else
            {
                ++iI;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ++iI;
        }
    }
    if ( pcSource[iStartSubStr]) // last sub string
    {
        ++iWordsCount;
    }

    return iWordsCount;
}

int main()
{
    char pcSource[]="cocacola";
    char pcSeparator[]="co";
    int iWordsCount;

    iWordsCount = wc(pcSource,pcSeparator);
    printf("Words count in this string are: %d\n",iWordsCount);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to use an existing function (`strstr`), to search for the separator. `strtok` may be an alternative, but I'm not sure it fits your requirements completely.

On second thought this looks a little too obfuscated...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int wc(const char *s, const char *sep)
{
    int seplen = strlen(sep);
    int count = 0;
    const char *p = s;        // last place where I found a separator
    while (p && *s) {         // if I found a separator and there are still characters to check
        p = strstr(s, sep);   // look for a separator
        count += !p || p > s; // if I didn't found one or found one with some characters in between, there is a word
        s = p + seplen;       // continue searching after current separator
    }
    return count;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *test[][2] = {
        { "cocacola", "co" },
        { "dadadad", "dad" },
        { "xdadadxad", "dad" },
        { "xdadadadx", "dad" },
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("Words count in \"%s\" is %d\n", test[i][0], wc(test[i][0],test[i][1]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```